# For Goblin Grenade can you sacrifice a creature that attacked?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My boyfriend plays a Goblin deck that absolutely destroys. But he has a combo that he does where he will attack with all of his creatures, and then sac one off after it has dealt damage to the player, and use Goblin Grenade. Can he do that? That just seems too op to me, because if he has multiple goblin grenades in one had he could sac all creatures that just dealt damage and that just doesn't make sense to me.

If there is a specific rule that says he can't do that, would you mind linking it for me?

Comment: Note that it's not longer an "attacking creature" after the Combat Phase is over, when the sacrifice actually happened in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the Goblins in question survive combat and Goblin Grenade is cast during the Second Main Phase this is perfectly legal.

This is a common strategy for Goblin decks to deal as much damage as they can as fast as they can regardless of the cost to them. While this allows them to make some very powerful plays like sacrificing Goblins to Goblin Grenade, it also makes them very fragile. For example if you are able to counter the Grenade they still have sacrificed the Goblin as part of the cost for paying the spell, so they are down a lot of resources that are going to make it harder for them to win the game. So while in the right deck Goblin Grenade is very strong I would not call it OP or broken.

Comment: Thanks! I guess we can stop fighting about it now lol. I think I just got bitter because he had Quest for Pure Flame out with 4 quest counters on it and wrecked me in a single turn. His decks can be very irritating.

Comment: Yeah, Goblins can be annoying like that at times. If you are wanting strategies to beat him try to do things that give you card advantage while giving you dudes or removing his like Wall of Omens or Forked Bolt

Answer (score 2):

If the attacking creature survives the attack, it can be sacrificed to a [Goblin Grenade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Grenade) that's cast after the combat is over. There's not so much a rule allowing this as there's no rule against it.

---

Here's what happens during combat:

1. 507 Beginning of Combat Step

   1. 507.3 Both players get to play instants and abilities.
2. 508 Declare Attackers Step

   1. 508.1 The active player declares his attackers.
   2. 508.3 Both players get to play instants and abilities.
3. 509 Declare Blockers Step

   1. 509.1 The defending declares his blockers.
   2. 509.2 The active player declares the damage assignment order of his attackers.
   3. 509.3 The defending player declares the damage assignment order of his blockers.
   4. 509.5 Both players get to play instants and abilities.
4. 510 Combat Damage Step (First Strike and Double Strike)

   1. 510.1 Combat damage is assigned.
   2. 510.2 Combat damage is dealt (simultaneously).
   3. 510.4 Both players get to play instants and abilities.
5. 510 Second Combat Damage Step (non-First strike and Double Strike)

   1. 510.1 Combat damage is assigned.
   2. 510.2 Combat damage is dealt (simultaneously).
   3. 510.4 Both players get to play instants and abilities.
6. 511 End of Combat Step

   1. 511.2 Both players get to play instants and abilities.

As you can see, you can cast instants and activate abilities at a number of points in the turn.

- One can cast instants and activate abilities after an attacker has been declared, but before blockers have been declared. [CR 508.3]

  If he sacrifices the attacker here, he might as well have done it before attacking.
- One can cast instants and activate abilities after blockers have been declared but before damage is dealt. [CR 509.5]

  If he sacrifices the attacker here, he want deal any damage to the blocker.
- One can cast instants and activate abilities after damage has been dealt.  [CR 510.4]

  The attacker and the blocker will already have dealt damage to each other by this point, so the attacker would have had to survive the blocker's damage to be around to do this.
- The one thing that's not possible to to have a creature deal combat damage and sacrifice it before it gets damaged (unless it has First Strike or Double Strike). This used to be possible, but that hasn't been the case since Magic 2010 was released mid-2009.

---

But at none of those times can Goblin Grenade be cast because it's a Sorcery, not an Instant.

You can only cast Sorcery spells in one of your Main Phases. But there is a Main Phase after the Combat Phase has completed.

> 505.1. There are two main phases in a turn. In each turn, the first main phase (also known as the precombat main phase) and the second main phase (also known as the postcombat main phase) are separated by the combat phase (see rule 506, “Combat Phase”). The precombat and postcombat main phases are individually and collectively known as the main phase.

The first chance the attacker would have to cast Goblin Grenade sacrificing a creature that participated in combat is in the postcombat Main Phase.

> 505.5. Third, the active player gets priority. Players may cast spells and activate abilities. The active player may play a land.

Comment: If it was worded "sacrifice an untapped Goblin", then your friend couldn't do it because the Goblin would (presumably) be tapped from attacking. But that's not the case.